# Importing a 3rd party jar on Maven and IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, maven, jar

I know there are tons of questions and answers about this problem, but none of them helped.

I have a jar, which I would like to import to my local java project.

I have created the project on IntelliJ IDEA with Spring Initializer.

I have used this command to install the jar into ~/.m2 repo

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:/Users/xxxx/Desktop/xxxx/lib/mylib-1.2.11.jar /
-DgroupId=com.test.custom -DartifactId=mylib -Dversion=1.2.11 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Then I have added these lines into my pom.xml file

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.test.custom</groupId>
            <artifactId>mylib</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
```

I have no errors, everything seems in order.

However, when I want to import a class from that jar.

import com.ca.bla.bla.MyClass

I receive an error called "Cannot resolve symbol "MyClass".

How can I solve it?

I have tried to create a lib folder and copy the jar in it and add it as a module

I have tried to create a localrepo for maven

They all gave me the same result...

Thanks in advance

Comment: is your Intellij IDEA's project configured to read maven's pom.xml file to manage classpath for your project ?

Comment: how can i check that? I am kind of new to this world :)

Comment: In IntelliJ, go to the class in your code that it is complaining about, right-click and choose "Go To -> Declaration" or just use the hotkey "ctrl + b" with the cursor on the class. Does it navigate anywhere? It should navigate to somewhere in your "external files" folder in your project view (view that lists all of your classes). If not, something is off.